# Users create/join groups

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-meta, user-roles

I'm looking to create user groups in wp I don't want to use any plugin as it won't be suitable in this case.

Would the best approach be to use a custom post and allow users to create a post within that custom post type which would be the user group. The only problem I can foresee with this is that a group would need multiple users which in-turn means the custom post type would need multiple users assigned to it, is this possible?

The other method I had in mind was using user roles. This means a user would need to be able to create a user role and other users could then join this user role. I'm not sure which is any is most appropriate.